# Replace a key of object in java script by dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, localization

```
console.log(lang)
alert(lang.es.greeting);
alert(language);
```

above lang is an object of javascript and i have to replace key es dynamically by the value of language variable which is alert in last.Currently in language variable value is es also but i have to assign this dynamically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Your question isn't very clear!

Comment: And if what i understood right...
you can assign dynamically like `var lang={}; lang[language]='';`

Comment: lang={}
lang.en={
 greeting:"Hello",
}
lang.es = {
    greeting: "Hola",
    warning: "Atención"
};

Comment: i defined lang as above

Comment: Perhaps `alert(lang[inLanguage].greeting);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from dot notation to subscripting in order to access a property by the value of a variable.

```
var lang = {};
lang.en = { greeting:"Hello" };
lang.es = { greeting: "Hola", warning: "Atención" };

var inLanguage = 'en';
alert(lang[inLanguage].greeting); // alerts "Hello"

inLanguage = 'es';
alert(lang[inLanguage].greeting); // alerts "Hola"
```